# adding facebook share button in gwt application

Tags: facebook, gwt, gxt, facebook-share

I have been working with gwt and gxt since around few months,

I am working on a web site which needs to interact with social media web site like facebook,

I am trying to add fcebook share button in  my web site , i tried below way -

I tried using HTML -

```
    HTML facebookButton = new HTML();
                    facebookButton.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

facebookButton.setHTML("<div class=\"fb-share-button\" data-href=\"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/\" data-layout=\"button\" data-size=\"small\" data-mobile-iframe=\"true\"><a class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/......src=sdkpreparse\"> <img src=\"img/social/facebook.png\"  > </a></div>");
```

But it does nothing -

tab.getUrlHeader() - this what i want to share

i searched across , but could not find anything .

is it possible to create such button in gwt/gxt by any way ..?

any help is appreciated

Comment: This need the JS SDK to be embedded as well to do _anything_ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
facebookButton.setHTML("<div class=\"fb-share-button\" data-href=\"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/\" data-layout=\"button\" data-size=\"small\" data-mobile-iframe=\"true\"><a class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/......src=sdkpreparse\"> <img src=\"img/social/facebook.png\"  > </a></div>");
```

i think this what you copied from facebook share button -

This is correct , can't understand why this is not working for you.

You can try the iFrame approach. It is simple and easy.

I guess you have already created the facebook APP id from your developer account.

go to this page -

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
```

[image]

then enter the url you want to share -

URL to share

also choose the layout and the button size -

Layout-
Button Size-

Then click on Get Code - You will get the pop up.

In this pop up go to iframe tab - and copy the iframe element.

Then you can set this in your Html Label in GWT like this.

```
facebookButton.setHTML("<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=......");
```

Let me know if it works